# adding dot on top right corner on label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, badge

Hello i am creating swift app and i am want to add red dot on `UILabel` but i can't find solution how to do that i want output like below

[i want to achive something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Swr.png)

i have check many solution but that all if for `UIButton` but i need to implement on `UILabel`
i have refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236210/swift-add-badge-to-navigation-barbuttonitem-and-uibutton)

can any one have any solution for this than kindly help me

Comment: could you please share your code? we need to know what you've done before

Comment: You can subclass a UILabel and then create your own layout. Basically create a Swift file that inherits from UILabel and add visual element with code or make it in a .xib file. 

If you are unfamiliar with writing the code layout just use the interface builder to make your label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
func addlabelBadge(label:UILabel,text:String,fontSize:CGFloat = 17.0) {
        let size: CGSize = text.size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)])
        let point = CGPoint(x: size.width, y: 0)

        let circle = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: point.x+5, y: 10), radius: 5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi*2, clockwise: true)
        circle.path = path.cgPath
        circle.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        label.layer.addSublayer(circle)
    }
```

call this function at **viewDidLayoutSubviews**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    addlabelBadge(label: myLabel,text:"Badges")

}
```

or You call this function on button tap

```
@objc func didClickedMyButton(){
        addlabelBadge(label: myLabel,text:"Badges")
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

you can remove the dot calling

```
myLabel.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you! this helpful to me but i want red do  right after last letter like "Badge" than i want dot after "e" and if now i change "Badge"  to "Badges" than i want dot after "s" please help me out

Comment: Okay Thank you !

Comment: @David check the updated answer. You need to calculate the text length and get a point.then you can draw the dot using that point. make sure match the function font size to your label font size

Comment: Thank You Very Much its Work Like Charm For me!